# Changing Razor ActionLink querystring with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a list of notes in my application and depending on the selected note on the page at the time I want to delete that note when the delete button is clicked. I have run into a bit of trouble I have not been able to change the ActionLink querystring, or id property to reflect the selected notes.
I have tried a number of different ways, but no success. 
Below is my actionlink

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteNote", new { id = Model.TagNo }, new { @class="btn btn-danger", @id="btnDeleteNote"})
```

Where we see "id = Model.TagNo", I want to insert my own custom value there

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
$('.btnDelete').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn-danger').attr('href', '@Url.Action("DeleteNote", "Delete", new { id = "----" })'.replace("----", "CustomValueHere"));
});
```

your action link should render to an a tag and this will replace the href portion of that a tag with a new link.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks allot for reply. I tried your approach but unfortunately it didnt work for me. The link produced looked like this:  /Cows/Details/@Url.Action("DeleteNote",%20"Delete",%20new%20%7B%20id%20=%20"CustomValueHere"%20%7D)

Comment: are you running this script on your view?  If run on the view the Url.Action will be converted into a url.

Comment: Yes matt I was. I found another approach that works although im not sure it best MVC practice                  $("#btnDeleteNote").attr("href", "../DeleteNote/" + data[3]);
Thanks the help